# Как обновить версию git ветки до последней?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

У меня есть master и dev ветки, допустим нас 2 разработчика и оба коммитим в dev ветку, можно ли мне получить самую свежую версию этой ветки постоянно не качая зипку с репозитория?

Comment: [Учите, практикуйте!](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/)

Answer (score 1):

Для этого есть команды, которые как раз это и делают. Базовый шаги могут быть такие.

1. Необходимо настроить удаленный репозиторий.

   $ git remote add [shortname] [url]
2. Получить последние изменения

   $ git fetch [remote-name]
3. Если у вас были изменения, сделать merge
4. Если нет, можно просто сделать rebase.

Чтобы не набирать команды можно использовать например [TotoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/)

Рекомендую почитать книгу по [Git](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2)

Comment: git pull origin dev не сработает?

Comment: @SOUTHYYY [это вам пригодиться](https://files.jrebel.com/pdf/zt_git_cheat_sheet.pdf)

Comment: Если все текущее изменения в локальном репозитории закомичены, то сработает